# A probability of the power of a random variable, but inside an integral

Tags: probability, integration, expected-value

In "Concentration inequalities - A nonasymptotic theory of independence" by Boucheron et al. I found this weird statement I can't quite understand. It says, for a random variable $X$ which is a Gaussian (but I think it holds for any random variable):
$$
\mathbb{E}[X^{2q}] = \int_0^{+\infty}\mathbb{P}(X^{2q}>x)dx = \int_0^{+\infty}2qx^{2q-1}\mathbb{P}(X>x)dx
$$

I managed to prove the first equality (it follows from a nice decomposition of the expected value as $\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_0^{+\infty}(1-\mathbb{F}_X(x))dx+ \int_{-\infty}^{0}\mathbb{F}_X(x)dx$ ), but I don't understand the second equality.

Can somebody help me ?
:)

Comment: I believe you meant "first equality" in your question ?

Comment: No, I mean the second one. The first one I got.it By the way, I corrected a typo in the last expression. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Yeah sure, I'm looking at the second one. I just wrote this cause you wrote "first inequality". I'll edit it :)

Comment: Oh thank you, didn't realized :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $x \ge 0$ it holds: $$P(X^{2q} > x) = P(X > x^\frac{1}{2q})$$

And so we get:
$$\mathbb{E}[X^{2q}] = \int_0^{+\infty}\mathbb{P}(X^{2q}>x)dx = \int_0^{+\infty}P(X > x^\frac{1}{2q})dx$$

Now by substituting $y = x^\frac{1}{2q} \iff y^{2q} = x$ and considering $$\frac{dx}{dy} = 2qy^{2q-1} \iff dx = 2qy^{2q-1}dy$$

we have
$$\int_0^{+\infty}P(X > x^\frac{1}{2q})dx = \int_0^{+\infty} P(X > y)2qy^{2q-1}dy =  \int_0^{+\infty}2qy^{2q-1} P(X > y)dy$$

and we are done.

Comment: This was so easy lol.Thank you so much :)